# SQL - get first match of Where criteria - MS Access

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a a dataset of sales looking something like this

```
Product  sold.date
apple    01/jan/2012
banana   01/feb/2012
orange   01/mar/2012
```

in the same periode there will be campaigns i.e.

```
Campaign name      start           end
campaign1        01/jan/2012     15/feb/2012
campaign2        01/feb/2012     01/mar/2012
```

In SQL, how do I get just 1 campaign in which a product was sold? that is, banana is sold in campaign1 OR campaign2, not counted as a sale twice.

It does not matter which campaign the sales is counted on. There will be multiple rows of sales that will overlap more then 1 campaign.

Any help would be great...

Comment: The facts indicate that the banana was sold in the period in which the 2 campaigns overlap. So your business now needs to define a rule as to how they would want to interpret this information before any SQL can be written?

Comment: sold.date >= [Start date] and
sold.date <= [end date]

Comment: Doesn't matter which campaign the sale is counted on..

Answer (score 1):

#### Get 1 campaign for 1 product

You did not name your RDBMS. In **PostgreSQL** or **MySQL** you could use `LIMIT 1`.

```
SELECT p.Product, c.Camgaign
FROM   p
LEFT   JOIN c ON p.sold_date BETWEEN c.start AND c.end
WHERE  p.Product = 'banana'
-- ORDER BY <something>
LIMIT  1;
```

I use `LEFT [OUTER] JOIN` to return the 'banana' row, even if there is no matching campaign. Campaign would be `NULL` in that case.

Use `ORDER BY` to *select* a campaign by some available criteria instead of getting just an arbitrary one that qualifies.

In **MS SQL** you would use `SELECT TOP n`.
In **Oracle** `WHERE rownum <= 1`;

---

#### Get 1 campaign for all products

```
WITH x AS (
    SELECT p.Product, c.Camgaign
          ,row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY p.Product) AS rn
    FROM   p
    LEFT   JOIN c ON p.sold_date BETWEEN c.start AND c.end
    WHERE  p.Product = 'banana'
    )
SELECT Product, Camgaign
FROM   x
WHERE  rn = 1
   OR  rn IS NULL;  -- to include prod. without campaign
```

Tested in **PostgreSQL**, works in **MS SQL Server** or **Oracle**.
Does not work in **MySQL** which support neither CTEs nor window functions.

Comment: But I dont just want the banana row. I want all the sales joined up to whatever campaign they are sold in. But just 1 campaign name per sale

Comment: @AndreasMuurholm: I left MS ACCESS behind 10 years and never looked back. May be similar to MS SQL, I could not say. Next time, remember to mention your RDBMS to begin with - as well as other details like you mention in the comment.

Comment: Looks great - I am using MS Excel to call another workbook. I think syntax is MS Access. How would that look?